# Why using angular directive for select, the first option change is an empty option with "?" as value?

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel

At the beginning, when the selection is loaded, it's fine, but when I changed the option it shows me as option selected an empty select, then it works fine

HTML:

```
<select name="questionId1" class="questionId1 form-control required" tabindex="3" ng-model="abCtrl.questions.question1" ng-options="question.value as question.val for question in abCtrl.form.questions track by question.index"></select>
```

JS:

```
 for(var i in $scope.getSecurityQus.questions){
            self.form.questions.push({index:i-6, key:i, val:$scope.getSecurityQus.questions[i]});
        }

        self.questions.question1 = self.form.questions[0];
        self.questions.question2 = self.form.questions[1];
```

RESULT after the first change:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"> </option>
    <option label="question ONE" value="0" selected="selected">question ONE</option>
    <option label="question TWO" value="1">question TWO</option>
    <option label="question THREE" value="2">question THREE</option>
<option label="question FOUR" value="3">question FOUR</option>
```

Comment: Can you post your code for HTML?

Comment: I've put html of the select and of the options, which html part do you mean (need)?